# Keras custom decision threshold for precision and recall

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, keras

I'm doing a binary classification using `Keras` (with `Tensorflow` backend) and I've got about 76% precision and 70% recall. Now I want to try to play with decision threshold. As far as I know `Keras` uses decision threshold 0.5. Is there a way in `Keras` to use custom threshold for decision precision and recall?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: For completion's sake: Keras now natively includes a threshold(s) parameter for metrics based on True/False Positives/Negatives.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

create custom metrics like this :

**Edited thanks to @Marcin** : Create functions that returns the desired metrics with `threshold_value` as argument

```
def precision_threshold(threshold=0.5):
    def precision(y_true, y_pred):
        """Precision metric.
        Computes the precision over the whole batch using threshold_value.
        """
        threshold_value = threshold
        # Adaptation of the "round()" used before to get the predictions. Clipping to make sure that the predicted raw values are between 0 and 1.
        y_pred = K.cast(K.greater(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1), threshold_value), K.floatx())
        # Compute the number of true positives. Rounding in prevention to make sure we have an integer.
        true_positives = K.round(K.sum(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        # count the predicted positives
        predicted_positives = K.sum(y_pred)
        # Get the precision ratio
        precision_ratio = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
        return precision_ratio
    return precision

def recall_threshold(threshold = 0.5):
    def recall(y_true, y_pred):
        """Recall metric.
        Computes the recall over the whole batch using threshold_value.
        """
        threshold_value = threshold
        # Adaptation of the "round()" used before to get the predictions. Clipping to make sure that the predicted raw values are between 0 and 1.
        y_pred = K.cast(K.greater(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1), threshold_value), K.floatx())
        # Compute the number of true positives. Rounding in prevention to make sure we have an integer.
        true_positives = K.round(K.sum(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        # Compute the number of positive targets.
        possible_positives = K.sum(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))
        recall_ratio = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
        return recall_ratio
    return recall
```

now you can use them in

```
model.compile(..., metrics = [precision_threshold(0.1), precision_threshold(0.2),precision_threshold(0.8), recall_threshold(0.2,...)])
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: @NassimBen  nice solution. I would like to do something quite similar but dynmaically caclulate the `threshold_value` based on the `kth` largest value in `y_pred`: I've asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720458/keras-custom-recall-metric-based-on-predicted-values

Comment: if I give it different threshold values and save the model at what precision or recall value the model will the model will be saved ?

Comment: here is [another method] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041931/is-there-an-optimizer-in-keras-based-on-precision-or-recall-instead-of-loss), I don't know why these two code produce different results for the same threshold, and they are all different from the value I count with the predict result (while keras_metrics.precision()  returns the correct answer for 0.5 threshold).

Comment: @Mohsin I believe the model won't save precision or recall value at all. They are for evaluation only. After a training, you may save weights, these weights are aim to reducing loss value.