# Use TensorFlow loss Global Objectives (recall_at_precision_loss) with Keras (not metrics)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, auc, precision-recall

## Background

I have a multi-label classification problem with 5 labels (e.g. `[1 0 1 1 0]`). Therefore, I want my model to improve at metrics such as fixed recall, precision-recall AUC or ROC AUC.

It doesn't make sense to use a loss function (e.g. `binary_crossentropy`) that is not directly related to the performance measurement I want to optimize. Therefore, I want to use TensorFlow's `global_objectives.recall_at_precision_loss()` or similar as loss function.

- Relevant GitHub:
  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/global_objectives
- Relevant paper (Scalable Learning of Non-Decomposable Objectives): https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04802

### Not metric

I'm not looking for implementing a `tf.metrics`. I already succeeded in that following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50566908/3399066

## Problem

I think my issue can be divided into 2 problems:

1. How to use `global_objectives.recall_at_precision_loss()` or similar?
2. How to use it in a Keras model with TF backend?

### Problem 1

There is a file called `loss_layers_example.py` on [the global objectives GitHub page (same as above)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/global_objectives). However, since I don't have much experience with TF, I don't really understand how to use it. Also, Googling for `TensorFlow recall_at_precision_loss example` or `TensorFlow Global objectives example` won't give me any clearer example.

How do I use `global_objectives.recall_at_precision_loss()` in a simple TF example?

### Problem 2

Would something like (in Keras): `model.compile(loss = ??.recall_at_precision_loss, ...)` be enough?
My feeling tells me it is more complex than that, due to the use of global variables used in `loss_layers_example.py`.

How to use loss functions similar to `global_objectives.recall_at_precision_loss()` in Keras?

Comment: Hi! I am also trying to integrate the loss functions from Global Objectives into Keras. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I don't think I found the solution, but with TensorFlow 2.0 integrating Keras, it might be easier?

Comment: The original link is now broken because TF is not maintaining it any more. [New link pointing to archive location](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/archive/research/global_objectives)

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Martino's answer, but will infer shape from input (setting it to a fixed batch size did not work for me).

The outside function isn't strictly necessary, but it feels a bit more natural to pass params as you configure the loss function, especially when your wrapper is defined in an external module.

```
import keras.backend as K
from global_objectives.loss_layers import precision_at_recall_loss

def get_precision_at_recall_loss(target_recall): 
    def precision_at_recall_loss_wrapper(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = K.reshape(y_true, (-1, 1)) 
        y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, (-1, 1))   
        return precision_at_recall_loss(y_true, y_pred, target_recall)[0]
    return precision_at_recall_loss_wrapper
```

Then, when compiling the model:

```
TARGET_RECALL = 0.9
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=get_precision_at_recall_loss(TARGET_RECALL))
```

Comment: Just in case someone else runs into this. This does not work with 1.14.x 1.15.x if you import Keras via `tensorflow.keras`. If you `pip3 install keras=2.2.5` and import 'keras' (not `tensorflow.keras`) it works !

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work by:

- Explicitly reshaping tensors to BATCH_SIZE length (see code below)
- Cutting the dataset size to a multiple of BATCH_SIZE

```
    def precision_recall_auc_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = keras.backend.reshape(y_true, (BATCH_SIZE, 1)) 
        y_pred = keras.backend.reshape(y_pred, (BATCH_SIZE, 1))   
        util.get_num_labels = lambda labels : 1
        return loss_layers.precision_recall_auc_loss(y_true, y_pred)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could provide a bit more code, so that people can execute a minimal example? From where are you calling your function `precision_recall_auc_loss()`? From which library is `util`? Are you using Keras with TensorFlow 2.0?

Comment: I tried using this today with TF2.x. Unfortunately, the loss_layers.precision_recall_auc_loss fails due to TF1.x usage patterns. Specifically, it's not clear to me how one should proceed regarding the use of model_variable after doing an automated upgrade using tf_upgrade_v2. However, the upgraded loss_layers.roc_auc_loss did work using this exact same pattern out of the box and provided improved results for my use case!

Comment: Just in case someone else runs into this. This does not work with 1.14.x 1.15.x if you import Keras via `tensorflow.keras`. If you `pip3 install keras=2.2.5` and import 'keras' (not `tensorflow.keras`) it works ! (havent tried with tf2)